# Formdata Dimensional Arrays Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

```
var bArray= [];
for (var i = 0; i <= indexCount; i++) {
    var baslik = $("#baslik_" + i).val();
    var aciklama = $("#aciklama_" + i).val();
    if (baslik && aciklama) {
        var cArray= new Array();
        cArray.push(baslik);
        cArray.push(aciklama);
        bArray.push(cArray);
    }
}
```

After this I am appending formdata (formData.append("myArray", bArray);) and sending via ajax but I am getting different value. I try formData.get("myArray"); and the result is a different value. Why ?

**UPDATE**

I am getting  a,b,c,d but I am giving my value like this [[a,b],[c,d]].

Comment: So, here we need to determine the real data, which is sent in the request.
Could you provide that data?

What's the result you got?

Comment: I update my question and answer you.

Comment: Yep, that's clear. When you provide the array, it will be stringified via `toString()` method. So the `[1,2]` becaming `1,2` and `[3,4]` becaming `3,4`. So, the eventual Array `[[1,2], [3,4]]` will be `1,2,3,4`. Just a try: `[[1,2], [3,4]].toString()`

Comment: but I need get the value like how I send.Is there any way for this